# Having a catchable fatal error

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a customer that is having a Catchable fatal error. I was wondering if anyone else had faced this error before?

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class
>   Requests_Utility_CaseInsensitiveDictionary could not be converted to
>   string in
>   /home/content/p3pnexwpnas13_data02/57/3071357/html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-gateway-authorize-net-cim/lib/skyverge/woocommerce/class-sv-wc-plugin.php
>   on line 400

I'm still not very comfortable with PHP and would like some help on what I should be looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and error message after updating to WooCommerce version (2.6.4) and WordPress (4.6).

I updated the WooCommerce Authorize.Net AIM plugin (https://woocommerce.com/products/authorize-net-aim/) from version 3.5.1 to version 3.9.2 and the problem was resolved.